# AngularJS Datatables with Bootstrap 4 - Formatting issues

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, datatables, angular-datatables

I can't seem to find an easy fix to correct styling issues with AngularJS Datatables using Bootstrap 4.  Everything formats correctly except for the pagination and search (which appear on the left hand side):

[image]

Does anyone know of a fix to push these elements back to the RHS?
I have tried adding custom `DOM` styling but to no avail (so I have just kept it standard for now)

```
.withDOM( 'lfrtip' )
.withBootstrap()
```

I've also included the Bootstrap 4 .`js` file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>`

I know it has something to do with the `DOM` styling (and I am assuming something to do with `flex` ) but I can't work out the correct combination to style it properly.

Comment: Okay, I have found the culprits in the `angular-datatables.bootstrap.js` file that is affecting the styling: (1) `'sWrapper': 'dataTables_wrapper form-inline'` should just be `'sWrapper': 'dataTables_wrapper'` and (2) `dom: '<\'row\'<\'col-xs-6\'l><\'col-xs-6\'f>r>t<\'row\'<\'col-xs-6\'i><\'col-xs-6\'p>>'` should have the `col-xs-6` values changed to `col-sm-6`.  That allows the styling to work correctly and everything formats nicely, until you press the back button and for some reason, the `DOM` is dropped from the datatable.  Meaning there is no longer `rows` with `col-sm-6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for any one who is experiencing the same formatting issues using `AngularJS Datatables` with Bootstrap 4, this is what I did to get around it:

Modified the `angular-datatables.bootstrap.js` file from this:

```
function _overrideClasses() {
    /* Default class modification */
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        'sWrapper': 'dataTables_wrapper form-inline',
        'sFilterInput': 'form-control input-sm',
        'sLengthSelect': 'form-control input-sm',
        'sFilter': 'dataTables_filter',
        'sLength': 'dataTables_length'
    });
```

To this:

```
function _overrideClasses() {
    /* Default class modification */
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        'sWrapper': 'dataTables_wrapper',   // Removed the form-inline
        'sFilterInput': 'form-control input-sm',
        'sLengthSelect': 'form-control input-sm',
        'sFilter': 'dataTables_filter',
        'sLength': 'dataTables_length'
    });
```

And then modified all my datatables `.withDOM()` from this:

```
.withDOM( 'lfrtip' )
.withBootstrap()
.withPaginationType( 'full_numbers' )
```

To this:

```
.withDOM( '<\'row\'<\'col-sm-6\'l><\'col-sm-6\'f>r>t<\'row\'<\'col-sm-6\'i><\'col-sm-6\'p>>' )
.withBootstrap()
.withPaginationType( 'full_numbers' )
```